# Why can't I set the gravity for my view

Tags: android

I want to set the gravity of a view (in my .java file) but for some reason it can't be done this time (it states that there is no such method). But normally `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` will just be considered valid code.

So why can't it be done all the time? What should I do when I can't set the gravity of a view but I still want to align it to mid( like `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`)?

```
AScrollView middle = new AScrollView(context);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams formid = 
new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

middle.setLayoutParams(formid);

middle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); //This can't be done..
```

Comment: ....what class does it extend?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly why you can't set `Gravity` on `ScrollView` but I'm pretty sure you can't. However, if you have a `ScrollView` then you should have some `Layout` or content inside of it to scroll. Simply set the `Gravity` on that `Layout` and it should give you the effect you want

Answer (score 0):

use this way..First add the view middle then after try to set gravity

```
formid.addView(middle) ;
middle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout Gravity is not supported by `RelativeLayout`. It is supported e.g. by LinearLayout where you can set it via the public property `gravity` of the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code. 

        ScrollView middle = new ScrollView(this);
        middle.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER));
```

let me know the status.